# User.Identity.Name in Web Api Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I went through the answer to some of the already existing questions and none of the answers are working for me.

In the ProfileController, I invoke the WebApi Controller as follows:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var webApiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiURL"]; 
    var response = client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}", webApiUrl, "//api/ProfileWeb")).Result;
    var profile = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Profile>().Result;
    if (profile != null)
    {
        _profileModel.Id = profile.Id;
        _profileModel.FirstName = profile.FirstName;
        _profileModel.LastName = profile.LastName;
        _profileModel.PhoneNumber = profile.PhoneNumber;
        _profileModel.EmailAddress = profile.EmailAddress;
    }
    return this.View(_profileModel);
}
```

In the Api Contoller, I get the userName as follows:

```
public class ProfileWebController : ApiController
{
    private IReminderDb _db;

    public ProfileWebController(IReminderDb db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public object Get()
    {
        string userName = User.Identity.Name;    // <-- Not working..
        var profile = _db.GetProfile(userName);
        return profile;
    }
}
```

Inside the web api controller, I am not able to get the User.Identity.Name that is in the ProfileContoller. According to some other answers where I have tried Thread.CurrentPrincipal but still the User.Identity.Name is coming out as null in web api controller.

What am I missing?